# Bash customization - How can blank spaces be left before the command output?

Tags: bash

I want to customize my terminal so that some blank spaces appear before the command output shows. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image: "Ideal" prompt to be more readable]

The second part of the image (with the blank spaces) is Gimp-ed and is exactly what I am looking for. I have read about PS1-PS4 customizations but I don't seem to find the right place to implement this idea.

Edit: I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199208/how-can-i-prepending-a-character-for-every-output-of-a-command) post but it does not provide any answer. It also points to a reddit question which stays unresolved.

Comment: Some commands test the width of the window and adjust their output to fit, so in general this isn't a good idea. If you want to make your commands stand out more, you could colour them, or make them use the bold font as hinted at in [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/239869/119298).

Comment: That is actually completely true. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will insert 4 spaces at the start of any line sent to stdout:

```
exec 1> >(sed 's/^/    /')
```

It uses a bash process substitution.

You might consider adding a newline to your prompt to separate commands in order to add clarity

Comment: It seems that `sed` buffers a lot. Consider adding `-u`.